# How do you find the limits of integration without drawing a picture?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Consider the integral $$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx.$$ I need some help understanding how to find the new limits of integration if I'm evaluating the integral in polar coordinates.

I've drawn part of the picture, a circle centered at the origin with a radius of 1, and I understand why the limits for dr are from 0 to 1, but I don't know what to do with the limits for d(theta).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Why don't you want to draw a picture?  Carefully setting up the inequalities to use is a way of "almost" doing a picture.

Comment: So I tried graphing part of it, but I'm not sure what the limits 1 and -1 tell me. :( The graph I have is of a circle with radius 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to polar coordinates is not required until after integrating with respect to y. $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^0\mathbb{d}y\,\mathbb{d}x=\int_{-1}^1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathbb{d}x=2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathbb{d}x$
(note that the negative sign may be removed since $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is half of the unit circle $r=1$, and therefore the area above $f(x)$ is equivalent to the area below $\sqrt{1-x^2}$)
Hint: Try making the substitution $x=\sin(\theta)$ such that $\mathbb{d}x=\cos(\theta)\,\mathbb{d}\theta$. No graphing is required, merely an understanding of the key values of $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: How would I convert 1 and -1 for integrating with polar coordinates though??

Comment: At what value of $\theta$ on the interval $[0,\,2\pi)$ is $\sin(\theta)=1$? What about $\sin(\theta)=0$?

Comment: Do you mean cos(theta)? Since those are the limits of integration for dx?

Comment: Both would work, though making the substitution $x=\sin(\theta)$ would be easier to evaluate.